# Update two tables, each on separate MySQL servers, on two different machines in one query?

Tags: mysql, replication, php, table

I have two MySQL servers running on two different machines in a local network. I am using PHP and accessing the databases via IP. No problems there. The databases have identical schemas. One of them was an import from the other machine.

I want to run a single (ONE) query that updates the same table on each server simultaneously. I already have existing queries and do not want to update them extensively.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

I'm looking to keep the databases in sync when an update occurs.

I am also open to any other suggestions regarding other ways to keep the databases in sync.

Comment: What you are looking for is [replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html). Don't rely on your application to keep things in sync.

Answer (score 0):

If you update one server only, [master/slave replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/replication.html) is sufficient, otherwise [group replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-replication-summary.html) or [galera](http://galeracluster.com/documentation-webpages)